# For any language $L_1$ and $L_2$ if $L_1 \subseteq L_2$, then ${L_1}^* \subseteq {L_2}^*$

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I am tempted to say no, since you can not say that an infinite set is a subset if an an infinite set. Unless you are talking about something like the natural numbers is a subset of the real numbers but here they are talking about any language. Any pointers?

Comment: Actually I think it's true that ${L_1}^* \subseteq {L_2}^*$, since  although $L_2$ and $L_1$ are infinite $L_2$ will always contain all the elements of $L_1$ and at least one element not in $L_1$.

Comment: You most definitely can say that an infinite set is a subset of another infinite set.  "$A$ is a subset of $B$" just means that every element of $A$ is also in $B$.  It doesn't imply that $A$ is 'smaller' than $B$.  (For example the even numbers are a subset of the integers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. Assume $L_1 \subseteq L_2$. We then have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ that $L_1^n \subseteq L_2^n$. This implies that

$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} L_1^n \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} L_2^n $

which is just the definition of $L_1^*\subseteq L_2^*$.